# Node installing issue in laravel 5

Tags: node.js, laravel

I had problem with running `npm install` in laravel i got error to use admin access, so I used `Command Prompt` and install it successfully, then when i ran `npm run dev` I've got error again and suggested to use latest version of node, so i download it and install it again.

Then I checked my `node` and `npm` version trough Command Prompt and my app terminal `(which is set to my laravel directory)` here is what i get:

https://ibb.co/fQU9Pc

[image: screen1]

any idea why i get 2 different version of node & npm in my system and my laravel app?

Comment: `sudo npm install n -g` // download 'n' package to upgrade node.
`sudo n stable` // for latest stable release

Comment: @SushantMagoo using windows, sudo is linux.

Comment: run it without `sudo`

Comment: @SushantMagoo run in my system directory or my laravel app directory?

Comment: `npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@2.1.8: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: uninstall node from your system. Try [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to keep multiple version of node